# hide and show button with animation,iphone

Tags: iphone, animation, uibutton

To hide or show a button in a view I am using

```
myButton.hide = YES or myButton.hide = NO
```

I am looking for the way to show a button animatedly such as slowly fade in

Does anybody know how to do it,Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `UIView` animation.
Here is simple implementation:

```
// to hide
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
    delay:1.0
    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
    animations:^{
        myButton.alpha = 0.0
    } 
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
        NSLog(@"Done!");
    }];

// to show (implement in another method)
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
    delay:1.0
    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
    animations:^{
        myButton.alpha = 1.0;
    } 
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
        NSLog(@"Done!");
    }];
```

Here is a good tutorial for this: [How To Use UIView Animation Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial)

You might want to take a look at the documentation too: [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

There are also similar QA's in this website: e.g. [How can I animate a UIButton Alpha property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470356/how-can-i-animate-a-uibutton-alpha-property-with-monotouch)

Hope it helps!